# Document viewer like ViewerJS, that can embed an <iframe> in an html page, but for postscript files

Tags: html, documentation-viewer, postscript

I'd like to display **postscript** files within <iframe>'s on my html pages, pretty much exactly like I'm already doing for pdf files using https://viewerjs.org/ with a tag something like 
      
**<iframe src="/ViewerJS/#../somefile.pdf" width=400 height=300></iframe>**
Except that I want that to be **somefile.ps** instead of **.pdf**.

I know I could use ImageMagick **convert somefile.ps somefile.pdf** (or similar), but these postscript files are being generated in real time, and attempts using such converters actually take too long, given our requirements.

Comment: <p>It is almost certainly not what you have in mind, but I suppose <a href="https://github.com/zaphod42/PostscriptJS">PostScriptJS</a> should be mentioned.</p>

Comment: @Alan Thanks. I took a look at that, but couldn't quite figure out what his Viewer.js code is doing (not too familiar with js), and his ps.html test page that uses it isn't working. I tried messing around with it a bit, but without any success.